# Mousetrap.bindGlobal is not a function

Tags: reactjs, npm, mousetrap

I installed Mousetrap through npm and have been trying to get Mousetrap.bindGlobal to work but this is the error it gives me

```
Uncaught TypeError: mousetrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.bindGlobal is not a function
```

This doesn't make sense because when I import mousetrap in my jsx file, vscode shows that the command is valid. Any help with this would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

`bindGlobal` is in the TypeScript definition, but not in the NPM package. It's an extension.

You can see the documention [here](https://craig.is/killing/mice#extensions.global).
You can either add the extension manually, or add it with NPM/Yarn. I couldn't find any official package, but [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mousetrap-global-bind) seems to be working fine.

```
$ npm i mousetrap-global-bind
$ yarn add mousetrap-global-bind
```

To make it work, you need to add Mousetrap, then the extension.

```
import mousetrap from 'mousetrap';
import 'mousetrap-global-bind';
```